# Leinster's Category theory model answers

Tags: category-theory

Is there a source of model answers for the examples in Leinster's Basic Category theory?

The book has an excellent set of questions but sadly no apparent answers are provided, despite the book being aimed at those with no previous experience learning outside of lectures. As a graduate moving into mathematics from physics the ability to see the rigorous formulation of the answers would be a godsend (Never mind those that leave me stumped).

Comment: Probably not, since the book is new. You could probably get some full answers to individual questions here, especially if you post your own efforts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I belong to a group that is working through Leinster's book, and I have posted some solutions. I will be updating this from time to time.

Update: The group finished the book. A greatly expanded set of solutions is now available [from my web page](https://diagonalargument.com/mathnotes/).

Comment: Thank you, these were helpful.

Comment: That's good reason to buy the book. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is interested, I also wrote down solutions to all exercises in the book (I was not aware of the other set of solutions above).

You can find them here: https://positron0802.wordpress.com/basic-category-theory-leinster/